# How to handle NotFoundException elegantly in Neo4j 2.0?

Tags: java, cypher, neo4j

We were wishfully thinking that with Neo4j 2.0, concurrently querying and deleting nodes will no longer throw NotFoundException. Our previous system using Neo4j 1.9.3 was full of checks to handle this exception(very ugly code). **Is there any better way to handle NotFoundException(if not eliminate) in neo4j 2.0 or, in the pipeline?**

Stack Trace:

```
org.neo4j.graphdb.NotFoundException: Node 2432 not found
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.NodeManager.getNodeForProxy(NodeManager.java:425)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.state.OldTxStateBridgeImpl.deleteNode(OldTxStateBridgeImpl.java:111)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.state.TxStateImpl.nodeDoDelete(TxStateImpl.java:250)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.StateHandlingStatementOperations.nodeDelete(StateHandlingStatementOperations.java:100)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.ConstraintEnforcingEntityOperations.nodeDelete(ConstraintEnforcingEntityOperations.java:140)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.LockingStatementOperations.nodeDelete(LockingStatementOperations.java:196)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.OperationsFacade.nodeDelete(OperationsFacade.java:428)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.spi.v2_0.TransactionBoundExecutionContext$NodeOperations.delete(TransactionBoundExecutionContext.scala:132)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.spi.v2_0.TransactionBoundExecutionContext$NodeOperations.delete(TransactionBoundExecutionContext.scala:130)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_0.spi.DelegatingOperations.delete(DelegatingQueryContext.scala:92)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_0.spi.ExceptionTranslatingQueryContext$ExceptionTranslatingOperations.org$neo4j$cypher$internal$compiler$v2_0$spi$ExceptionTranslatingQueryContext$ExceptionTranslatingOperations$$super$delete(ExceptionTranslatingQueryContext.scala:118)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_0.spi.ExceptionTranslatingQueryContext$ExceptionTranslatingOperations$$anonfun$delete$1.apply$mcV$sp(ExceptionTranslatingQueryContext.scala:118)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_0.spi.ExceptionTranslatingQueryContext$ExceptionTranslatingOperations$$anonfun$delete$1.apply(ExceptionTranslatingQueryContext.scala:118)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_0.spi.ExceptionTranslatingQueryContext$ExceptionTranslatingOperations$$anonfun$delete$1.apply(ExceptionTranslatingQueryContext.scala:118)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_0.spi.ExceptionTranslatingQueryContext.org$neo4j$cypher$internal$compiler$v2_0$spi$ExceptionTranslatingQueryContext$$translateException(ExceptionTranslatingQueryContext.scala:149)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_0.spi.ExceptionTranslatingQueryContext$ExceptionTranslatingOperations.delete(ExceptionTranslatingQueryContext.scala:118)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_0.spi.UpdateCountingQueryContext$CountingOps.delete(UpdateCountingQueryContext.scala:118)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_0.mutation.DeleteEntityAction.org$neo4j$cypher$internal$compiler$v2_0$mutation$DeleteEntityAction$$delete(DeleteEntityAction.scala:50)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_0.mutation.DeleteEntityAction.exec(DeleteEntityAction.scala:36)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_0.pipes.ExecuteUpdateCommandsPipe.org$neo4j$cypher$internal$compiler$v2_0$pipes$ExecuteUpdateCommandsPipe$$exec(ExecuteUpdateCommandsPipe.scala:56)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_0.pipes.ExecuteUpdateCommandsPipe$$anonfun$org$neo4j$cypher$internal$compiler$v2_0$pipes$ExecuteUpdateCommandsPipe$$executeMutationCommands$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(ExecuteUpdateCommandsPipe.scala:45)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_0.pipes.ExecuteUpdateCommandsPipe$$anonfun$org$neo4j$cypher$internal$compiler$v2_0$pipes$ExecuteUpdateCommandsPipe$$executeMutationCommands$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(ExecuteUpdateCommandsPipe.scala:45)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:371)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:371)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_0.pipes.EmptyResultPipe.internalCreateResults(EmptyResultPipe.scala:28)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_0.pipes.PipeWithSource.createResults(Pipe.scala:71)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_0.executionplan.ExecutionPlanBuilder.org$neo4j$cypher$internal$compiler$v2_0$executionplan$ExecutionPlanBuilder$$prepareStateAndResult(ExecutionPlanBuilder.scala:149)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_0.executionplan.ExecutionPlanBuilder$$anonfun$3.apply(ExecutionPlanBuilder.scala:136)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_0.executionplan.ExecutionPlanBuilder$$anonfun$3.apply(ExecutionPlanBuilder.scala:135)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_0.executionplan.ExecutionPlanBuilder$$anon$6.execute(ExecutionPlanBuilder.scala:50)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.ExecutionPlanWrapperForV2_0.execute(CypherCompiler.scala:93)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.ExecutionEngine.execute(ExecutionEngine.scala:61)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.ExecutionEngine.execute(ExecutionEngine.scala:55)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.javacompat.ExecutionEngine.execute(ExecutionEngine.java:65)
    at net.ahm.graph.ConcurrDeleteLab$1.run(ConcurrDeleteLab.java:65)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744
```

Source code to simulate the issue:

```
package net.ahm.graph;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.neo4j.cypher.javacompat.ExecutionEngine;
import org.neo4j.cypher.javacompat.ExecutionResult;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.DynamicLabel;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.GraphDatabaseService;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Node;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Transaction;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseSettings;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.schema.IndexDefinition;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.schema.Schema;
import org.neo4j.kernel.impl.util.FileUtils;
import org.neo4j.kernel.impl.util.StringLogger;

public class ConcurrDeleteLab {
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(CypherLab.class);
    private final static int CONCURRENCY = 4;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        FileUtils.deleteRecursively(new File("graphdb"));
        final GraphDatabaseService graphDb = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabaseBuilder("graphdb")
                .setConfig(GraphDatabaseSettings.use_memory_mapped_buffers, "true").setConfig(GraphDatabaseSettings.cache_type, "strong")
                .newGraphDatabase();
        registerShutdownHook(graphDb);
        LOG.info(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> NUMBER OF PARALLEL CYPHERS: " + CONCURRENCY);
        LOG.info(">>>> STARTED GRAPHDB");
        createIndex("Entity", "name", graphDb);
        try (Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx()) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
                Node child = graphDb.createNode(DynamicLabel.label("Entity"));
                child.setProperty("name", "entity" + i);
            }
            tx.success();
        }
        LOG.info(">>>> CREATED NODES");
        final ExecutionEngine engine = new ExecutionEngine(graphDb, StringLogger.SYSTEM);
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            try (Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx()) {
                ExecutionResult result = engine.execute("match (n:Entity) return n.name");
                for (Map<String, Object> row : result) {
                    assert ((String) row.get("n.name") != null);
                }
                tx.success();
            }
        }
        LOG.info(">>>> WARMED UP");
        ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(CONCURRENCY);
        final CountDownLatch cdl = new CountDownLatch(CONCURRENCY);
        for (int i = 0; i < CONCURRENCY; i++) {
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                es.execute(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try (Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx()) {
                            long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
                            engine.execute("match (n:Entity) delete n");
                            LOG.info(">>>> CYPHER TOOK: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - time) + " m-secs");
                            tx.success();
                        } catch (Throwable t) {
                            LOG.error(t);
                            t.printStackTrace();
                        } finally {
                            cdl.countDown();
                        }
                    }
                });
            } else {
                es.execute(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try (Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx()) {
                            long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
                            ExecutionResult result = engine.execute("match (n:Entity) return n.name");
                            LOG.info(">>>> CYPHER TOOK: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - time) + " m-secs");
                            int count = 0;
                            time = System.currentTimeMillis();
                            for (Map<String, Object> row : result) {
                                assert ((String) row.get("n.name") != null);
                                count++;
                            }
                            LOG.info(">>>> GETTING RESULTS TOOK: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - time) + " m-secs");
                            tx.success();
                            LOG.info(">>>> CYPHER RETURNED ROWS: " + count);
                        } catch (Throwable t) {
                            LOG.error(t);
                            t.printStackTrace();
                        } finally {
                            cdl.countDown();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
        cdl.await();
        es.shutdown();
    }

    private static void createIndex(String label, String propertyName, GraphDatabaseService graphDb) {
        IndexDefinition indexDefinition;
        try (Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx()) {
            Schema schema = graphDb.schema();
            indexDefinition = schema.indexFor(DynamicLabel.label(label)).on(propertyName).create();
            tx.success();
        }
        try (Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx()) {
            Schema schema = graphDb.schema();
            schema.awaitIndexOnline(indexDefinition, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            tx.success();
        }
    }

    private static void registerShutdownHook(final GraphDatabaseService graphDb) {
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                LOG.info("### GRAPHDB SHUTDOWNHOOK INVOKED !!!");
                graphDb.shutdown();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: And I assume you don't want to catch the exception?

Comment: We were expecting repeatable read kind of behavior within a single cypher. If catching the exception and retrying is the most elegant thing out there and we are already doing it.

Comment: I think you should report it to github issues and see if they'll change the functionality. I prefer the no-exception model that they've been going toward with a lot of other changes.

Comment: Hi, can you please share the url where i can report it to ?

Comment: https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/new

Comment: I think for now you're stuck with this, this will go away as soon as MVCC is fully implemented. But until then raising the issue to push awareness is the best thing you can do. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is currently not a better option.
This issue was reported here in 2012:
https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/37