# NotFoundException merge relationship type for first time

Tags: neo4j, cypher

On a fresh db of neo4j (2.0.1)  the first time I run this query I get a 400 with a NotFoundException angry at the 5th relationship.  Technically all these relation types are new since it's the first query to hit the db.  This doesn't break my app but just curious if I am using a bad technique here.  Does it have something to do with the WITH clause?

```
// Match possible mutual friend pattern
"MATCH (user:User {userId:{userId}})-[:FRIEND]-(mutualFriend:User)-[:FRIEND]-(possibleFriend:User) " +
"WHERE NOT (user)-[:FRIEND]-(possibleFriend) " +
"AND NOT (user)-[:FRIEND_INVITATION]-(possibleFriend) " +
"WITH user, possibleFriend, count(mutualFriend) AS mutuals " +
// Create suggestion from user to suggested friend
"MERGE (user)-[suggestion1:FRIEND_SUGGESTION]->(possibleFriend) " +
"ON CREATE SET suggestion1.mutual=mutuals, suggestion1.ignore=false, suggestion1.facebook=false " +
"ON MATCH SET suggestion1.mutual=mutuals " +
// Create suggestion in opposite direction too
"MERGE (user)<-[suggestion2:FRIEND_SUGGESTION]-(possibleFriend) " +
"ON CREATE SET suggestion2.mutual=mutuals, suggestion2.ignore=false, suggestion2.facebook=false " +
"ON MATCH SET suggestion2.mutual=mutuals " +
// Return total number of suggestions created or updated
"RETURN count(suggestion1) + (suggestion1) AS total";
```

Here is the response from neo4j:

```
{
  "message" : "Relationship 5 not found",
  "exception" : "NotFoundException",
  "fullname" : "org.neo4j.graphdb.NotFoundException",
  "stacktrace" : [ "org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.NodeManager.getRelationshipForProxy(NodeManager.java:547)", "org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.state.OldTxStateBridgeImpl.deleteRelationship(OldTxStateBridgeImpl.java:144)", "org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.state.TxStateImpl.relationshipDoDelete(TxStateImpl.java:264)", "org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.StateHandlingStatementOperations.relationshipDelete(StateHandlingStatementOperations.java:104)", "org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.ConstraintEnforcingEntityOperations.relationshipDelete(ConstraintEnforcingEntityOperations.java:147)", "org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.LockingStatementOperations.relationshipDelete(LockingStatementOperations.java:203)", "org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.OperationsFacade.relationshipDelete(OperationsFacade.java:443)", "org.neo4j.cypher.internal.spi.v2_0.TransactionBoundExecutionContext$RelationshipOperations.delete(TransactionBoundExecutionContext.scala:171)", "org.neo4j.cypher.internal.spi.v2_0.TransactionBoundExecutionContext$RelationshipOperations.delete(TransactionBoundExecutionContext.scala:169)", "org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_0.spi.DelegatingOperations.delete(DelegatingQueryContext.scala:92)", "org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_0.spi.ExceptionTranslatingQueryContext$ExceptionTranslatingOperations.org$neo4j$cypher$internal$compiler$v2_0$spi$ExceptionTranslatingQueryContext$ExceptionTranslatingOperations$$super$delete(ExceptionTranslatingQueryContext.scala:118)", "org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_0.spi.ExceptionTranslatingQueryContext$ExceptionTranslatingOperations$$anonfun$delete$1.apply$mcV$sp(ExceptionTranslatingQueryContext.scala:118)", "org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_0.spi.ExceptionTranslatingQueryContext$ExceptionTranslatingOperations$$anonfun$delete$1.apply(ExceptionTranslatingQueryContext.scala:118)", "org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_0.spi.ExceptionTranslatingQueryContext$ExceptionTranslatingOperations$$anonfun$delete$1.apply(ExceptionTranslatingQueryContext.scala:118)", "org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_0.spi.ExceptionTranslatingQueryContext.org$neo4j$cypher$internal$compiler$v2_0$spi$ExceptionTranslatingQueryContext$$translateException(ExceptionTranslatingQueryContext.scala:149)", "org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_0.spi.ExceptionTranslatingQueryContext$ExceptionTranslatingOperations.delete(ExceptionTranslatingQueryContext.scala:118)", "org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_0.spi.UpdateCountingQueryContext$CountingOps.delete(UpdateCountingQueryContext.scala:118)", "org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_0.mutation.DeleteEntityAction.org$neo4j$cypher$internal$compiler$v2_0$mutation$DeleteEntityAction$$delete(DeleteEntityAction.scala:53)", "org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_0.mutation.DeleteEntityAction.exec(DeleteEntityAction.scala:37)", "org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_0.pipes.ExecuteUpdateCommandsPipe.org$neo4j$cypher$internal$compiler$v2_0$pipes$ExecuteUpdateCommandsPipe$$exec(ExecuteUpdateCommandsPipe.scala:56)", "org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_0.pipes.ExecuteUpdateCommandsPipe$$anonfun$org$neo4j$cypher$internal$compiler$v2_0$pipes$ExecuteUpdateCommandsPipe$$executeMutationCommands$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(ExecuteUpdateCommandsPipe.scala:45)", "org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_0.pipes.ExecuteUpdateCommandsPipe$$anonfun$org$neo4j$cypher$internal$compiler$v2_0$pipes$ExecuteUpdateCommandsPipe$$executeMutationCommands$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(ExecuteUpdateCommandsPipe.scala:45)", "scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:371)", "scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:371)", "org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_0.pipes.EmptyResultPipe.internalCreateResults(EmptyResultPipe.scala:28)", "org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_0.pipes.PipeWithSource.createResults(Pipe.scala:71)", "org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_0.executionplan.ExecutionPlanBuilder.org$neo4j$cypher$internal$compiler$v2_0$executionplan$ExecutionPlanBuilder$$prepareStateAndResult(ExecutionPlanBuilder.scala:149)", "org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_0.executionplan.ExecutionPlanBuilder$$anonfun$3.apply(ExecutionPlanBuilder.scala:136)", "org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_0.executionplan.ExecutionPlanBuilder$$anonfun$3.apply(ExecutionPlanBuilder.scala:135)", "org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_0.executionplan.ExecutionPlanBuilder$$anon$6.execute(ExecutionPlanBuilder.scala:50)", "org.neo4j.cypher.internal.ExecutionPlanWrapperForV2_0.execute(CypherCompiler.scala:93)", "org.neo4j.cypher.ExecutionEngine.execute(ExecutionEngine.scala:61)", "org.neo4j.cypher.ExecutionEngine.execute(ExecutionEngine.scala:65)", "org.neo4j.cypher.javacompat.ExecutionEngine.execute(ExecutionEngine.java:78)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.web.CypherService.cypher(CypherService.java:100)", "java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.transactional.TransactionalRequestDispatcher.dispatch(TransactionalRequestDispatcher.java:139)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.security.SecurityFilter.doFilter(SecurityFilter.java:112)", "java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)" ]
}
```

Comment: at what part of your query is the exception coming? please elaborate a bit further your problem.

Comment: I added the response I get from neo4j.  I am assuming Relationship 5 is referring to [suggestion1:FRIEND_SUGGESTION], but could be wrong.

Comment: Your problem looks similar to other post . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21385630/how-to-handle-notfoundexception-elegantly-in-neo4j-2-0